# The steady state solution of a boundary value problem.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

From a question I posted earlier:

> Okay, my question that I have to solve is:
>
> ```
> u_tt - ku_xx = x      0<x<1 , t>0
>
> u(0,t) = 1      t>0
> u(1,t) = 0
> ```
>
> I know that steady state solutions do not depend on time.
>
> I just can't figure out how to start solving this. All of the examples
>   that we have in our textbook only have u_t and not u_tt. So I don't
>   really know how I should start this.
>
> I'm not asking for you to solve the problem. I just need help on how
>   to get it started.
>
> If anyone can help me it would be much apprieciated. Thanks.

---

Someone's advice was:

```
A steady state solution would be one for which  ut = 0 . If  ut = 0 , so is  utt . That is what you would use in the partial differential equation, so you now have an ordinary differential equation in  x  to solve. (This is like having a "stationary solution" for an ODE, but here it's a function of  x  , rather than just a number.) –  RecklessReckoner
```

So using their advice i got:

```
u"=-x/k and then i integrated it twice to get u = -(1/6k)(x^3)+c but i still need to apply the boundary conditions.

So if i used it from 0 -> 1, then c = 1/6k
```

but i am like so confused right now. I am clearly doing something wrong here. Because I dont even understand what the answer would be.

Would it be `u = -1/6k(x^3-1)???`

Please help. My entire assignment is based around this and i cant even get through one.

Comment: The tag [tag:differential-equations] is intended for questions about ordinary differential equations, there is a separate tag for [tag:pde]s; see the [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/differential-equations/info) and the tag-excerpt. (The tag-excerpt is also shown when you are adding a tag to a question.)

Answer (score 1):

Hint. If you integrate $u''=-x/k$ once, you obtain $u'=\frac{-x^2}{2k}+C_1$ (with a single integration constant $C_1$). Now integrate this once more. How many integration constants do you have now?

Now apply the  boundary conditions...

Answer (score 0):

The steady state solution is given by $$u(x)=-\frac{x^3}{6k}+\left(\frac{1}{6k}-1\right)x+1.$$